# Arreglo de Objetos

Tags: array, javascript-objeto

que tal un saludo y gracias por leer el post... mi consigna es una función recibe un numero como parámetro y regresa un arreglo de objetos que tiene una propiedad llamada valor la cual contiene el valor del numero y sus anteriores.

1.- primero se me ocurrió recorrer el numero y guardarlo en un array

2.- después recorrer el nuevo array y pasarlo como objeto

3.- logro obtener un objeto pero debo agregarle la propiedad valor para que quede asi:

arregloDeObjetos(5) debe retornar [{valor: 1}, {valor: 2}, {valor: 3}, {valor: 4}, {valor: 5}]

```
function arregloDeObjetos(num){
  let arr = [];
  let obj = {};
 for(let i = 0; i <= num; i++)
  arr.push(i)
 for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
   obj[i] = arr[i]
   return obj
```

}

let res = arreglodeObjetos(5); // res {0:0,1:1,2:2,3:3,4:4,5:5}

cualquier guia bienvenida, gracias¡

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si tu objetivo es imprimir `[{valor: 1}, {valor: 2}, {valor: 3}, {valor: 4}, {valor: 5}]` (un array de objetos) entonces deberías quitar el segundo `for` (ya que con ese segundo `for` estabas creado un objeto con posiciones), y modificar el anterior de tal forma:

```
function arregloDeObjetos(num){
  let arr = [];
  let obj = {};
 for(let i = 0; i <= num; i++)
  arr.push({'valor':i})
 return arr
}
arregloDeObjetos(5)
```

Comment: ({'valor': i}) esta sintaxis le indica a javascript que la key o propiedad del objeto se defina como valor?

Comment: @GualbertDev sí, por cada iteración, con push estás metiendo dentro del array un objeto {} con la propiedad 'valor' que vale i push({'valor': i}).
Entonces al final tienes un array con varios objetos, todos ellos con la propiedad valor, pero podrías añadir más propiedades haciendo push({'valor':i, 'prop2': 'valor2', 'prop3':'valor3'}), entonces cada posición del array sería un objeto con 3 propiedades.